# When I use float left content jumps out of the block

Tags: html, css, web, css-float

I have created my code sample on jsbin , here it is

http://jsbin.com/apaqon/4/edit

What i want to do is to make two setion left and right, but when i use float left on the block element it jumps out of the main block container..

In my code want to keep leftBlock and rightBlock inside the white background.

Can anyone please help me oout

Comment: did you try `display: inline;`?

Comment: yes. i did tried that out. don't why it is breaking

Comment: dear see my answer and let me know if any issues or i am lagging some where. The white space above your left and right content is Height of marquee, i have not touched marquee code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PBGyT/1/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PBGyT/1/embedded/result/

Just one line of css, i added overflow:hidden: `#Block{margin: 0px 20px; overflow:hidden;}`

See screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Why is this solve the problem? Could you give me a little insight under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

check your style rules,

you defined a class `.clear`, but you have no html tag with that class attribute. this is needed to actually float elements. 
if you add something like

```
<p class="clear"></p>
```

just before you close the content block div it will make both left and right boxes appear with a white background.

Comment: hmm i new to this forum so i dont know how to post code but what i was trying to post was adding a p tag and then applying a class of clear to it

Comment: Welcome to SO! For code blocks, simply indent by 4 spaces, with empty lines before and after. For more formatting help, click the orange question mark at the top right of the edit box.